# Storing a period of time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store a period of time in a MySQL database.

What I'm trying to do is store the period of time that is considered peak time say 7.30 - 9.30

Anyone have any suggestions that might help me out?

Thanks

Comment: No, it will always be the same

Comment: So you don't really need to store is at all. Bu juergen's solution is fine if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Ok thanks, I know i dont really have to store it but I gotta do it this way for a school project

Answer (score 2):

You could use 2 columns for that

```
startTime 
endTime
```

both using the `time` data type if it is always on a single day or use `datetime` if the period can extend a day.